# How to tell a Template that the Parameter is derived from a certain class

Tags: c++, templates

Right now, I'm writing a program on a feature-based approach. Every functionality besides the bare skeleton comes as its own package, derived from a feature class.

I have the Following Header definition:

```
class Feature
{
    public:
        Feature(std::string Name)
            : Parent(nullptr), Name(Name)
        {
            if (FeatureNames.count(Name) == 0)
                FeatureNames.insert(Name);
            else
                throw std::logic_error(std::string("Feature: The Feature with the name '") + Name + "' already exists");

        }


        virtual ~Feature(){}

        const std::string &getName(){ return Name; }
        virtual void shutDown() = 0;

    protected:
        Feature *Parent;

    private:
        static std::set<std::string> FeatureNames;
        std::string Name;
};

template<class ChildFeat>
class FeatureEx : public Feature
{
    public:
        FeatureEx(std::string Name) :Feature(Name){}
        virtual ~FeatureEx(){}
        void addChildFeature(ChildFeat *Child);

    protected:
        std::vector<ChildFeat*> Children;
};

//implementation
template<class ChildFeat>
void FeatureEx<ChildFeat>::addChildFeature(ChildFeat *child)
{
    Children.push_back(child);
    child->Parent = this;
}
```

And I have a Feat-class and a ChildFeat-Class, like the following:

```
class FeatureClass : public FeatureEx<MyChildFeatureInterface>
{
    ...
}

class MyChildFeat : public Feature, public MyChildFeatureInterface
{
     ...
}
```

When I now try to call the `addChildFeature()` method on an Instance of `FeatureClass`
the compiler is crying, because the `addChildFeat()` method only sees a `MyChildFeatureInterface`, which of course does not have the member `Parent`.

I could easily bypass this problem by deriving `MyChildFeatureInterface` directly from `Feature`, but on the one hand I find that sub-optimal and on the other hand I was wondering whether there is a way to tell the Compiler: "This template Argument, can be any class, BUT IT MUST BE DERIVED from class X".

Comment: There are two ways to use this kind of assertion: one (SFINAE) silently removes the function from the set of overloads considered whereas the other (`static_assert`) provokes a compilation error. Which one would you prefer ?

Comment: I guess the SFINAE-version is what Deduplicator posted? I know static assert. I was just hoping for something like template<class T: public X> which sadly does not work

Comment: You are right on all counts, yes :) It may be sad, but at least there is a work-around.

Comment: Why does `MyChildFeatureInterface` not inherit from `Feature`?  It seems the more correct code, and solves all your problems.

Comment: Because for me it feels cleaner to sepperate the functionality that exclusively depends on the Non-Feature-Parts of FeatureClass, from the functionality of the basic Feature-stuff, that is needed by the FeatureHost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can easily say to the compiler that a class must be derived from Base.

An example with a function:

```
template<class X> auto my_function1(X&& x)
-> decltype(*declval<const volatile Base**>() = &x, declval<void>());
```

If `x` is not a kind of `Base`, so does not derive from it, the assignment is ill-formed and thus the function is removed from consideration at the overload-resolution step.
I like this form, because it is immediately transferable to **checking any odd expressions you might want**.

Or using the pre-packaged tests from the standard-library as Matthieu M. rightly [mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265127/how-to-tell-a-template-that-the-parameter-is-derived-from-a-certain-class/25265250?noredirect=1#comment39367418_25265250) (only work on classes):

```
template<class X> auto my_function2(X&& x)
-> enable_if_t<is_base_of<Base, typename decay<X>::type>::value, void>;
```

Comment: ehm, I'm sorry if that seems like a dumb question, but I dont really get, what you are doing there. As far as I know decltype is used to declare a variable to be of the type of another object. Your lines dont make any sense to me. For me it looks like you are assigning an adress to an RValue and specifiy that as Return-Value, somehow mixed with the definition of a function pointer

Comment: It's a sneaky use of `decltype`, would not the [`is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) trait be more auto-explanatory ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It might. Though then one has to use `enable_if` too.

Comment: With `is_base_of`, chance are that you have to use `std::decay<X>::type`.

Comment: You need to use `std::decay<X>::type` anyway otherwise passing an lvalue attempts to form a pointer to an lvalue reference.